# Hiding keyboard on mobile Chrome doesn't change window height

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, mobile, mobile-chrome

When you open a keyboard on **mobile Chrome** (in my case iOS 7.0.3 and Chrome 33.0.1750.21), the height of the window changes. That's OK. But when you **hide the keyboard, the window doesn't change its height back**.

I made a simple demo, that writes window height when it's resized:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    $('#heights').prepend($(window).height() + '<br />');
}).resize();
```

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/orthes/QkFCZ/.

Just click on an input to open the keyboard, an then hide it.

What it does:

1. Default height is correct (in my case on iPad mini - 836px)
2. When I open the keyboard, window height is changed to 538px - this is still correct
3. When I close the keyboard, the resize event is not even fired - **here is, where the problems begin**
4. When I click on a link to get current window height manually, it writes 538px (event though it should be back to 836px)

Is it a known issue? Is there a workaround for it?

It affects me, when I want to use fixed positioned element with height 100%. Up on the load, the height is correct, but when I open and hide the keyboard, element's height doesn't resize back to 100%.

Comment: When I try the fiddle on iOS Chrome 41 in the CrossBrowserTesting emulator, the page zooms when I click in the input box, and never zooms back out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is a bug in the chrome/operating system combination. So to solve this you might want to consider changing the layout CSS of the page.

To see more information on the support of the resize event you can read here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/resize_mobile.html Look under full support Keyboard for resize when expanding keyboard.